# Add product to cart programmatically invalid request for adding product to quote

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart, quoteitem

I'm trying to create a controller to add a product to the cart programmatically in magento 1.9, like this:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction(){
    try {
      $productId = '146';

      $options = array('92'=>'49','144'=>'21');
      $insertData = array(
        'product_id' => $productId,
        'qty' => '1',
        'options' => $options
      );
      $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
      $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
      $cart->addProduct($product, $insertData);
      $cart->save();
      Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print_r($e->getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

But when I check the cart, it's still empty and I get an error like this:

```
Invalid request for adding the product to quote.
```

Comment: make sure product id and option id and value id

Comment: t@sunilpatel all correct

Comment: This is working for Magento 2 https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-customer-quote-add-products-quote/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$options = array('92'=>'49','144'=>'21');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(146);

$paramater = array('product' => '146',
                    'qty' => '1',
                    'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(),
                    'options' => $options 
            );       

$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($paramater);
$cart->addProduct($product, $request);
$cart->save();
```

Comment: i got this error: Please specify the product's option(s).

Comment: 'options' => array('option_id'=>'sub_option_id') replace with  $options = array('92'=>'49','144'=>'21');

Comment: i've done that, the 92 is code for color, and 144 is for size

Comment: @ShellSuite check my edited code

Comment: still got the same error

Comment: @ShellSuite are you trying add configurable product?

Comment: yes, i've found the solution change the 'options' to 'supper_attribute'

Comment: so you are trying to add configurable product  right?

Comment: yes configurable product

Comment: you need to mention into your question otherwise no code will work

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = new Varien_Object(['product'=> $product->getId(),
        'super_attribute' => array('92'=>'49','144'=>'21'),
        'qty' => $item->getQty(),
        ]);
$quote->addProduct($product, $params)->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $product_id = 1;
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $options = array(4 => 3, 5 => 1);
    $params = array(
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        'qty' => 1,
        'options' => $options
    );

    $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction(){
    try {
      $productId = '146';

      $options = array('92'=>'49','144'=>'21');
      $insertData = array(
        'product_id' => $productId,
        'qty' => '1',
        'options' => $options
      );
      $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
      $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
      $cart->addProduct($product, $insertData);
      $cart->save();
      Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print_r($e->getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

Remove getQuote() after Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session'), then test it again. You should no longer see an error.