# Magento 1.9 : Programmatically created cart not showing on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, quoteitem

I have below code to create cart and addProduct :

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(1);
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => 1)));
$quote->save();
```

Above code creating corresponding rows in quote tables, but when I'm checking on frontend cart page for same customer then I'm getting Cart is empty on cart page.

But when I try to addproduct in existing cart which is created from frontend using below code :

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($cartId);
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => 1)));
$quote->save();
```

then the programmatically added product is coming on frontend.

Why this is happening?

Comment: I hope [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173395/add-product-to-cart-programmatically-invalid-request-for-adding-product-to-quote/173398) will help you.

Comment: I tried the same code but it is not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue in your first code snippet is that, when you add product into cart and assign this product to customer Magento create a new entry in `sales_flat_quote` table but the flag `is_active` is `0`. So whenever you try to check frontend cart page for same customer, Magento load the quote with `is_active` `1` (If quote not found with `is_active` then It create a new quote).

So to solve this problem just set the flag `is_active` to 1. So your full code snippets looks like this,

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(1);
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => 1)));
$quote->setData('is_active', 1); // only add this line
$quote->save();
```

Comment: I checked and `is_active` column is 1 in table `sales_flat_quote` from my code. But `items_count` and `items_qty` are 0.