# How to add a single product with multiple quantities at a time to cart page in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to add product with multiple quantities on product detail page with additional add to cart button? Same as on [this](https://in.iherb.com/pr/Now-Foods-Ashwagandha-450-mg-90-Veg-Capsules/310) site

Can you please help me?

Comment: There is a Quanity box on product view page for this

Comment: Hi @ Piyush, This is my requirement.https://prnt.sc/hvwl2h

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: Yes, Above is the screenshot is my requirement

Comment: Please explain more, your requirement is not clear

Comment: For info find this link https://www.iherb.com/pr/Now-Foods-Ashwagandha-450-mg-90-Veg-Capsules/310    In this link add3cart button when I click this button 3 product quantities added to the cart I want to like that.

Comment: add a custom button on product page, on button click add product to cart from custom controller with 3 qty, [check this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/173395/20064) to add product programmatically

Comment: I will try.Thanks you respond to my question

Comment: Hi @ Piyush, Here only controller file is there remaining files is not there.Please send me all files.

Comment: Hi @ Piyush, Can you please help me this task?

Comment: Please add your code, what you have tried and what issue you are facing?

Comment: I added this code in <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><i class="icon-cart"></i><?php echo "add 3 to cart" ?></span></span></button>  addtocart.phtml file.I have click the button it add one quanitity but I want to add 3 quanities.Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi @ Piyush, Can you please help me?

Comment: All you want is another Button on product view page. And if we click on it that product should be added to cart with 3 qty. right?

Comment: Yaa.Can you please help me?